# Show users location on Globe instead of map in iOS 5 +

Tags: image, mkannotation, cllocation

I want to show users location with his profile image on Globe (Circular earth) instead of 2D map.  As per my knowledge , latitude & longitude which we get from CLLocationManager are converted from circular by making calculation to display it in 2D map . Correct me if I am wrong.

My question is it possible to display different users current location with his profile image on globe. Also I need option to pan (must have) & zoom (if possible) ?

Any kind of help , reference is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/107542-3d-interactive-globe-for-ios-app-development.html), you can use WhirlyGlobe to achieve the functionality.